# 301 Redirect for subdirectories Zeus

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, subdirectory, zeus

I have changed the name of my subfolder in my site and need to know the code for a rewrite.script

example:

how would I direct http://www.mydomain/stackoverflow/index

to

http://www.mydomain/stackoverflow2/index

I want to avoid writing each url path individually as the site is large. Please help im on a ZEUS server ARGH!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match URL into $ with ^/stackoverflow/(.*)
if matched then
      set OUT:Location = /stackoverflow2/$1
    set RESPONSE=301
    set BODY=Page moved
    goto END
endif
```